# Jquery UI not loading

Tags: content-editor-web-part, jquery-ui

I have a standard web part page and am reading items from a list and then displaying then under jquery tabs. I have downloaded the jquery UI (minified) and placed them in the site assets library of the site collection.

I have added a ref to the jquery UI files via script tags in the body of the html and called the html file using a content editor webpart.

The issue I am having is the jquery UI files do not download the first time the page is executed. Therefore the content is not rendered properly and no tabs are present. If I hit F5 to refresh after the page has loaded the page works fine however if I click on the nav menu on the left hand side (OTB nav) the Juery UI seems to load after the page is full executed and therefore this issue has comeback.

I have been told not to change the masterpage and therefore cannot add ref's to the jquery ui from there. Does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Did you get any errors in Browser console when the jQuery UI is not loaded?

Comment: Version of SharePoint? This sounds like the minimal download strategy in play, but we need to know if you are on 2013.

Comment: Eric I have just verified and the "minimal download strategy" has not been activated. I am using Sharepoint 2013 online (o365).

Answer (score 1):

it is essential for jquery ui that it is loaded AFTER jquery.
In my experience in most cases this is the problem.

To load your scripts at a specific time, try this approach: http://josharepoint.com/2015/06/16/custom-javascript-function-loaded-after-the-ui-has-loaded-in-sharepoint-2013/

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded could help you combined with lazy loading a script.